# Dynamically add different HTML tags to page using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

basically Im getting some information from the API and a loop will run and in that loop I need to add a h4 tag and button tag.

But when I run the loop the h4 tag is added but not the button.

Here is my code:

```
$http.get('/api/get_form_fields.php?id=' + $rootScope.user.id)
    .then(function(data) {
        if (data.data != null) {
            $.each(data.data, function(i, v) {
                if (v.required == "Yes" && v.type == "Upload") {
                    var text = "<h4>" + v.caption + "</h4>" + "<input type='file' value='test'>";
                    text = $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
                    $scope.htmlstring += text;
                }
            })
        } else {
            //no times available
        }

    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        $scope.divisions = error;
    });
```

But if I take out the '+' in the this line `$scope.htmlstring += text;` the button shows but only the last elements in the loop gets added to the page.

Thank you in advanced :)

Comment: What would work much better is to set up an ngRepeat with your h4 and button inside it, and bind it to an array, then in your loop append each data item to the array.